# Change bootstrap dropdown background to be just an image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a picture in a dropdown/dropup menu that I want to be the full background of the dropdown. I have an image set as the background but as you can see there is still white. How can I make the dropdown solely the image and have the scrollwheel in it?

While I'm at it, how would one go about changing scrollwheel css to be an image and such?

(I made the background green to showcase what I don't want to show)

[image]

Dropdown CSS

```css
        .dropdown-menu {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url('Res/IM/page.png');
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-color: #1e7e34;
        }
```

Relevant Dropdown Code

```
<div id="inv1" class="dropdown-menu" style="min-height: 35vh; resize: vertical;background-image: url('Res/IM/page.png'); background-size: 100% 100%;" >
                        <div class="scrollable">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv1" class="dropdown-header text-right">X</a>
                            <CODE IS HERE AND IRRELEVANT>
                        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?https://jsfiddle.net/40hn76b3/

Comment: your link to image probably not right `url('Res/IM/page.png');`

Comment: @לבנימלכה I updated my post and still have the same issue

Comment: As I said check your link to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this one?

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  background: url(https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/08/13/09/240_F_108130971_d2e6YQdGAfERW4p75YuJPQQsGZZXk41D.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: transparent ;
}

a.dropdown-item {
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold
}

a.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: transparent ;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated my post with this code and still have the same issue, any idea why this could be?

Comment: can you post a working snippet so we can go through your code

Comment: Try removing margin. `margin:0` in css for you `dropdown-menu`

Comment: Doesn't work. My image has a part of the background that is transparent, I think that could be it. How would I make the background color transparent?

Comment: `background-color: transparent` to make background transparent

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Is there a way to remove the little black outline surrounding the box? See [here](https://i.gyazo.com/38223606e0e2f59fc05b236f7b6810d0.png) for image

Comment: I guess thats the part of image or if there is any border for the background then apply `border:none` or `border:0` to remove borders. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dropdown-menu{
background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/949587/pexels-photo-949587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Check this code. I think this will solve your problem. :)

Comment: I updated my post with this code and still have the same issue, any idea why this could be?

Comment: have you included all cdns which is mentioned in my code?

Comment: Doesn't work. My image has a part of the background that is transparent, I think that could be it. How would I make the background color transparent?

Comment: @ItsOYo you can simply use background-color: transparent; for that

Comment: Somebody else got it all, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Np,Happy Coding :)